# MySQL Can't Connect to External Server

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to an external server on a fresh MySQL install, but it just seems to timeout. Access has been granted by the other servers admin to the particular account and ip address. I try running the following:

```
mysql --host=hostname -u username -ppassword database
```

But just get the following:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hostname' (110)
```

I have adjusted the following in my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

and restarted, but it didn't help. Any recommendations?

Comment: Is the MySQL server running on the host? Is there a firewall in the way?

Comment: It is running, I can connect from other servers that I have. There is a firewall, but it is disabled for these particular accounts.

Comment: Is this what you're using to access it? `mysql --host=hostname -u username -ppassword database`

Comment: try  ping command for mysql host or try telnet command with 3306 port in command line window. Make sure the grated IP address is your machine IP address or your network IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have checked that the firewall is letting MySQL traffic (usually port 3306) pass through and the service is running, the most probable cause is fine grained permission on the server. The user may not have been allowed to connect from any host, probably the permissions to connect are IP based or something similar.

Comment: There was a firewall issue in the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use that code but not providing the password, like:

```
mysql -h hostname -u username -p database
```

and intert the password after that command (it will ask for it).

Also you could try to provide a port: `--port=3306` for example.

You can also try to provide the protocol `--protocol=TCP`.

The only last idea that i have is that you dont provide the database and enter the database after you access the server...

sorry, can't do anything else from here with that data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to grant the user to access database from the remote computer.
to do that:

```
mysql> GRANT all on database.* to 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';
```

> this is not recomended becouse this will allow connection to your mysql server from anywhere. 
>   for allow connection to user in a certain ip address (we use 8.8.8.8 as example) use code below

mysql> GRANT all on database.* to 'username'@'8.8.8.8' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in your permisions granted to your user. try changing permisions and hope it will help you .